# How to convert a complex<float> variable into a float in C++?

Tags: c++, types, casting

I have a variable in my code that is a complex float.  I know that it only has a real part and I just want to type cast it to a float variable.

This should be super simple I feel but you can't just type cast and can't find the answer anywhere after over an hour of searching.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can't you just get the real part?

Comment: That is still in the complex float type.  At the end of the day I want to be able to compare it to another float variable.

Comment: @user3692250 So what is wrong with `someFloat == someComplex.real()`? (Besides the normal floating point compare issues of course).

Comment: What happened when you tried to compare it? Hint: it should have worked.

Comment: ^^ it has a 'real' getter, std::real(complexNumber)

Comment: @BaummitAugen Or even `someFloat == someComplex`.

Comment: It has a double/float overloads.

Comment: I get this error : cannot convert 'std::complex<float>' to 'float' in assignment

Comment: float realPart=std::real(complexNumber);

Comment: Okay never mind.  I was adapting someone else's code and they were creating a std::complex<"type"> variable which I assumed was just a complex<float> but type was actually complex<float> itself.  So I guess it was allowing me to create a complex<complex<float>> and that was causing the issues.

Comment: Regarding "what's wrong with", that's using `==` comparison on arbitrary floating point values. It's okay for floating point values that are known to be integers. But in general, even two values that are computed by apparently the same sequence of operations, can end up comparing unequal (due to internal conversions or lack of conversions to higher precision type).

Comment: @user3692250: Apparently you are inadvertently using `=` to compare instead of `==`. This is why you should always post a **minimal, complete example** that readers can try out. It ensures that you communicate the real problem. In passing, do note that comparing floating point values with `==` is in general a recipe for disaster. Required reading: the "What every scientist should know about floating point" article.

Answer (score 3):

There really isn't a "default" way to cast from a `complex<float>` to a `float`, because there are many interpretations:

1. Do you want the magnitude of the complex number? (`sqrt(re*re + im*im)`)
2. Do you want the magnitude squared? This avoids the expensive square root.
3. Do you want the real portion only?

Some frameworks that do a lot with Digital Signal Processing (such as X-Midas, Midas 2K, PicklingTools) explicitly do not allow such conversions.  They make the user pick the appropriate conversion *so the user doesn't lose information in the transformation*.  Having said, if you want just the real component, I feel some of the answers above were fine.  Here's a full, standalone program that illustrates:

```
#include <complex>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
  complex<float> cf(1.1, 2.2);
  float real_portion_only = cf.real();

  cout << real_portion_only << endl;
}
```

The compile line and run looks like:

```
  % g++ comp.cc -o comp
  % ./comp
  1.1
```